# Read from serial data length is always 1

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, platformio

Trying to read bytes from serial to buffer:

```
char buf[512];
if (int len = Serial.readBytes(buf, 512) > 0)
{
   DEBUG_LOGF("got bytes available=%d", len);
}else
{
   DEBUG_LOG("nothing read");
}
```

I'm always get `1` in `len` even it send data was long string. Strange thing is I found whole long string data in `buf`, while I still have `len==1`.

Why? How to fix that?

Comment: Hint: is the precedence of the assignment operator `=` higher or lower than that of the greater-than operator `>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of [*operator precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

The expression `int len = Serial.readBytes(buf, 512) > 0` is really equal to `int len = (Serial.readBytes(buf, 512) > 0)`.

That is, you assign the result of the comparison `Serial.readBytes(buf, 512) > 0` to the variable `len`.

You need to split the variable definition and the assignment to it, and use parentheses to get the correct precedence:

```
char buf[512];
int len;
if ((len = Serial.readBytes(buf, 512)) > 0)
```